Square matrices whose squares and pairwise products are zero
Suppose we have a set of $n\times n$ square matrices $\{L_i\}$. With the constraints $L_i^2 = 0$ and $L_i L_j = 0$, how to find the general form of $L_i$?
I have a feeling that, in some basis, they are just block off-diagonal matrices having no common entries, but am unable to prove it concretely.

One thing that one could say is that if $L_iL_j=L_jL_i=0$, then $(L_i+L_j)^2$ is also $0$, so $L_i+L_j$ is also nilpotent.

Any such set of $n\times n$ matrices that satisfies these conditions (all pairwise products and squares being zero) is equivalent to, after a change of basis, a set of matrices that are zero outside of a $k \times (n-k)$ submatrix in the upper-right corner.
It's pretty easy to see that any set of matrices that all vanish outside of the $k \times (n-k)$ submatrix in the upper-right corner will satisfy the conditions - try with an example. You perform multiplication by doing the dot product of a column with a row, and whenever you do this all the nonzero entries of a column, being the first k, hit the first $k$ entries of a row, which are all zero.  And this property - all products and squares being zero - will be preserved by conjugation, since its description is written without respecting any particular basis.
To see the converse, suppose we have a set of matrices $L$ satisfying this condition, and let $K$ be the intersection of all kernels, $$K = \bigcap_i \ker L_i.$$
Then, all $L$ map into $K$: if $v \in V$ ($V$ being the ambient vector space that is the domain of all $L$) then for any $i$, $L_j L_i v = 0$ for all $j$, so that $L_i v$ is in the kernel of all $L_j$ and hence in $K$.
If $K = 0$ then, since all $L$ map into $K$ by the above argument, all $L_i$ are $0$; but then $\ker L_i = 0$ for every $i$, and so $K = V$, implying $V = 0$. So, assuming $V \neq 0$, we have $K \neq 0$, and so let $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k$ be a basis of $K$, $k > 0$, and complete this to a basis $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ of $V$. The matrices for $L_i$ in this basis will $0$ outside of the $k \times (n-k)$ block in the upper-right corner: recalling that the $j$-th column of the matrix is given by the entries of $L_i b_j$ in this basis, we see that $L_i b_1 = \ldots = L_i b_k = 0$, and $L_i b_j$ for $j > k$ must be in $K$, ie in the span of $b_1, \ldots, b_k$, so that $L_i b_j$ has all of its nonzero entries in the first $k$ rows only.
Edit: Here's an explicit $3\times3$ example.  Take
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
10 & -15 & -80 \\
-4 & 6 & 32 \\
2 & -3 & -16
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix}
5 & -25 & -75 \\
-2 & 10 & 30 \\
1 & -5 & -15
\end{bmatrix}$$
You can check that $XX = XY = YX = YY = 0$.** So let's see if we can find a basis that puts it into the desired form.
To find the intersection of the kernels, we stack them, getting
\begin{bmatrix}
10 & -15 & -80 \\
-4 & 6 & 32 \\
2 & -3 & -16 \\
5 & -25 & -75 \\
-2 & 10 & 30 \\
1 & -5 & -15
\end{bmatrix}
Now we find a basis for nullspace (aka, kernel) of this matrix. This will also be the intersection of the nullspaces of the two matrices. (Do you see why?) We get the single null space basis vector $$\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
so we know that $\dim K = 1$ in this case.
Now complete this to a basis by adding in some more columns, getting
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1.
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now, writing the matrices for $X$ and $Y$ in the basis $B$ gives
$$B^{-1} X B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -3 & -16 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$B^{-1} Y B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -5 & -15 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and we see that they are both in the form I described above, all zero outside of the $k \times (n-k)$ submatrix in the upper right, with $k = 1$.
** If you wonder how I came up with $X$ and $Y$ in the first place, well, I cheated in a sense, by taking two matrices $X'$ and $Y'$ that have the above form and conjugating them by a random $T$ to get $X = TX'T^{-1}$, $Y = TY'T^{-1}$, in order to obfuscate their origin for this example.

Thanks! But, how do I determine number of basis vectors $k$? I mean, I don't know $K$ in general, and hence cannot construct a basis for it. Perhaps, an outline for $n=3$ case would definitely help.

If you have a list of all the matrices, you could concatenate all the $m$ matrices into the "tall" $mn \times n$ matrix and find a basis for the kernel.  That would be a basis for K. What exactly are you trying to do?

I added an explicit example.
